# SMS Text from Hyperlink on phone browser

Tags: sms

I need a way to have users on my website click an advertisement and have thier phone send a text message to a number with a keyword.  All they should have to do next is hit send.

User lands on my site.  Sees an ad that says "Click here to join our list" user clicks it and a number/keyword is loaded into their SMS Texting program on their phone so they hit send and they are on my list.

Comment: Can you wrap it as an app?  I know libraries such as Phonegap support sending SMS through their Javascript API.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
<a href="sms:12345678?body=TEXT_BODY_HERE">Click here to join our list</a>
```

where 12345678 is the phone number and TEXT_BODY_HERE is what you want them to send.  I haven't tested this, so I don't know what percentage of phones actually support this.

Comment: motorola droid3: body part appears in "to" box

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article with some details about forming SMS/Text message links:

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2166-how-to-send-a-text-message-from-your-mobile-website/

Samples:

```
<a href="sms://">Send an SMS</a>

<a href="sms://?body=Visit%20the%20best%20site%20at%20http://mobilexweb.com">
Invite a friend by SMS<a>

<a href="sms://+3490322111">Contact us by SMS</a>

<a href="sms://+3490322111?body=Interested%20in%20Product%20AA2">
More info for producto AA2</a>
```